# Problems with my 24h torrent box project (maybe related with ExFAT)

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, crash

I recently acquired a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B to make a 24h torrent box. My external HDD is in ExFat (1TB USB3.0 - WD) and after installing the exfat drivers, I began to configure it for my purpose. The problem was after adding the second torrent, but also appears also in the several tries with only one torrent.

The problem is that when I start the torrent client (in my case QBittorrent) it starts to download with a speed of 3-5MB/s, but after several seconds (less than 1 minute) it begins to fall until it stops to download. Sometimes it crashes, other times I need to force close, and the only hint that I have, is that is related with the exfat.mount process. I observed it while it was downloading and the use of CPU is a little high (about 15-20%).

Can someone help with this? I tried also changing the distro from Raspbian to Ubuntu Mate and changing several parameters of the cache, but always I experienced the same problem.

Comment: Try formatting the disk to ext3 or ext4. Also check SMART values.

Comment: The exFAT driver won't differ from distro to distro, and I believe it's performance is notoriously bad. As John says, it is not a wise choice of filesystem to use with linux due to licensing constraints imposed by MS.

Comment: I need the HDD at least on NTFS or ExFAT, because I use it to connect to the TV. 
It is the NTFS driver better than the ExFAT?

Comment: I have checked the manual of the TV and it only supports FAT16, FAT32 and exFAT file systems, so format it to NTFS cannot be the solution :(

Comment: Try ext anyway, just to see if that is the problem.

Comment: FAT formatting should work well but will limit the file size somewhat, also I think's its crap on on hard disks (also, some TVs may also not work well with HDDs). Alternatively, you could try and make it download the files to the SD card, and then sync the files to the USB drive every so often.

Comment: Oh, and [this driver](https://github.com/dorimanx/exfat-nofuse) may work better (or not, haven't tried it myself yet)